# Why does IDEA not find @android:drawable/ic_btn_search?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am defining an activity layout in IntelliJ IDEA. On an ImageButton, I set `android:src` to `@android:drawable/ic_btn_search` which seems reasonable to me, as I see there is a `ic_btn_search.png` file in the SDK resources under *data\res\drawable-mdpi* 
and *data\res\drawable-hdpi*

Moreover, the activity preview actually shows the image.

However, the validator says it cannot resolve this symbol, and as a result refuses to compile.

Am I specifying the resource incorrectly or is IDEA wrong? How can I otherwise set this image on the button?

Answer (score 2):

OK, this seems to be how it is:

According to [androiddrawableexplorer](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/), some resources are public and some aren't. To use the ones that aren't public, you have to copy them to your own resource directories and reference them with `@drawable/[image name]`.

It is odd though the IDEA's activity preview shows the image.